# define complex mutual exclusive arguments with argparse

Tags: python, argparse, mutual-exclusion

I know there is `ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()` which lets me choose between mutually exclusive options o1, o2, ..
Can I also define 'complex' argument groups which are mutually exclusive?

e.g. imagine I had to provide either username *and* password *or* a filename with credentials

```
my_program connect example.com --username me --password you
```

OR

```
my_program connect example.com --credential-file this/file.json
```

Of course I could define an option `--credentials` which would take both username and password so `add_mutually_exclusive_group` would be enough but I'm curious whether groups of arguments can be mutually exclusive, too.

Comment: No, the mutually-exclusive mechanism is a simple flat `xor` -  no subgroups with in it.  Do your post-parsing testing.

Comment: Previous SO have also suggested using the subparsers mechanism.