# With argparse is it possible to have subparsers with dashes?

Tags: python, argparse, mutual-exclusion

I want to specify "groups of arguments" like this:

```
fetch-something --basic-auth --user=me --password=myP4ss
```

OR

```
fetch-something --oauth --user=me --client=9038534.client --secret=aslu432409x
```

(similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175068/define-complex-mutual-exclusive-arguments-with-argparse))

I thought I could create subparsers `--basic-auth` and `--oauth` but it looks like subparsers added like this

```
auths = parser.add_subparsers(help='authentication-method', metavar="METHOD")
oauth_parser = auths.add_parser('--oauth')
```

will not recognize `--oauth` (with the dashes).

Is there any way to have something like a subparser but *with* dashes? Or any other way to describe a behavior like described without having to specify all requirements by checking existence and non-existence of arguments manually?

E.g.

```
fetch-something --oauth --user=me --password=abc --client=9038534.client --secret=aslu432409x
```

should be invalid because `password` must not provided together with `--oauth`

**Edit**:

maybe this still looks like a first world problem to you but another reason you might want to have this is *ordering*:

```
fetch-something --secret=aslu432409x --oauth --user=me --client=9038534.client
```

looks very strange since `--secret` is not visibly in scope of `oauth` any more but still valid.

**Approach**

One way one could probably go is to `parse_known_args` all (in this example) non-auth arguments and provide the rest to extra "auth-parsers"
for `basic-auth` and `oauth` which might raise if not provided with the correct arguments. Creating a complete help text would be hard then though..

Comment: The use of dashes to mark `flagged/optionals` is baked deep into the `argparse` code.  To the main parser, subparsers are actually `choices` of a `positional` argument.  Another central parsing goal is to accept flagged arguments in any order.  In general it follows POSIX practice that programmers have used for years.

Comment: Have you thought about what the usage help should look like?  Or what the error messages should be?